# %JAVA_HOME%\bin not working on Windows 8.1 for javac

Tags: java, java-home

There are a lot of posts about `JAVA_HOME`, but I couldn't find an answer for this:

- On Windows 8.1 command prompt, I was not able to run javac, getting
  the error: `'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`
- `javac is located at: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin`.  And,
- `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11`.
  Based on many suggestions here, I added to
- `PATH=....;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;` Unfortunately, system gave the same error message with javac.
- So I removed `JAVA_HOME` from `PATH` and replaced it with the fully qualified path.  Problem solved!
- My question: Does anyone know why the more elegant solution didn't work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to close your command window. User variables only take effect if you open the window again. Edit: I didn't down vote but this certainly isn't a good question on SO. Try http://superuser.com/

Comment: I was careful to close and reopen windows because many people had commented about it.

Comment: The downvotes are surprising, because a number of questions about JAVA_HOME got strongly upvoted.  Also if %JAVA_HOME%\bin doesn't work in PATH on Windows 8.1, then a number of user suggestions on StackOverflow are incorrect.

Comment: I have the same setup. It works fine.

Comment: I have the same setup (%JAVA_HOME%\bin; in path). That worked yesterday, today it does not work. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3):

I cannot comment yet, so I will give an answer instead.

I once had a similar problem on a Windows 7 system: Environment variables in my PATH (which is itself an environment variable) were no longer **expanded**. 
I found out that somehow the type of registry key that represents the PATH had changed from REG_**EXPAND**_SZ to REG_SZ.

The registry key is

```
HKEY_LM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SessionManager\Environment\Path
```

Actually you cannot change the type, instead you rename the original PATH entry, create a new one with the correct type ie REG_EXPAND_SZ and copy the value.

I can't remember the website which helped me back then, but this [Serverfault Environment variable...](https://serverfault.com/questions/300544/environment-variables-in-path-not-expanded-for-non-admin-command-prompt) describes the situation.

Answer (score 3):

1.Type jdk8(Java Development Kit) on your browser and click the first link(Java SE Development Kit 8 - Downloads - Oracle or [Click this link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).
[image]

2. Accept the License Agreement and select your windows version . Then click the link to download the  jdk8.

[image]

3.Then click the icon to install the jdk.

[image]

4.Click Next

[image]

[image]

5.Go to your C drive => program Files => java => jdk1.8.0_05 => bin

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

6.When you inside bin right click appletviewer and go to properties

[image]

[image]

7.Copy the location : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin

8.Click My computer => properties => Advanced system settings =>  Environment Variables

[image]

[image]

[image]

9.Under the system variables Find Path and click Edit.

[image]

10. Go to the end of the Variable value and add a semicolon ;  and paste (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin) Click Ok.

[image]

11. Open the command prompt (CMD) and type javac

[image]

Congratulation you have successfully install JDK8

Comment: How does this answer the question at all? Obviously OP has Java installed already.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I added JAVA_HOME into users variables, not SYSTEM variables, as req

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you may have added JAVA_HOME into **User Variable**.

Add JAVA_HOME into a **System Variable** it will work fine.